# Como substituir o conteúdo HTML de uma div usando DOMElement do php

Tags: php, html, dom, parser

Estou tentando desta maneira

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
//pegar o conteudo de um pagina web
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.astralsaudeambiental.com.br/');

$div = $doc->getElementById('sidebar');
$string_div = '';
foreach($div->childNodes as $node) {
   $string_div .= $doc->saveHTML($node);
}
if(!$div)
{
    die("Element not found");
}
//alterar o conteudo de um arquivo HTML em determinada div 
$content_doc = new DomDocument();
$content_doc -> loadHTML('<html><head><title>titulo</title></head><body><div                 style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#000000;"></div><div id="sidebar"></div></body>    </html>');
$content_doc -> getElementById('sidebar')->nodeValue = $string_div;
$content_doc_div = $content_doc -> getElementById('sidebar');
$content_doc_div_string = ''; 
foreach($content_doc_div->childNodes as $node) {
   $content_doc_div_string .= $content_doc->saveHTML($node);
}

echo $content_doc -> saveHTML();
```

Porém o conteudo e inserido no arquivo HTML de forma que apareça como texto

```
                &lt;div class="unidades box clear"&gt;
                &lt;h2&gt;Encontre a unidade mais próxima de você!&lt;/h2&gt;
                &lt;div&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;cConteudo.&lt;br&gt;
                    Use o campo abaixo para buscar a&lt;br&gt;
                    unidade mais próxima da sua cidade:&lt;/p&gt;
                    &lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Comment: Você quer gerar Html estruturado a partir de outro Html?

Comment: Tente utilizar o html_entity_decode() dentro do saveHTML().

Comment: Sim, quero inserir o conteudo de uma div de um site dentro de outro arquivo html, porém desta maneira as tags são tratadas como texto

Comment: não deu certo :/

Comment: Você pode tentar criar outro Documento para este pedaço de HTML e depois importar ele para a sua DIV, tipo assim:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400980/how-to-insert-html-to-php-domnode

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver essa questão, usando somente DOMDocument, você deve usar o [importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php), por se tratar de dois DOMDocument diferentes o link dessa documentação tem a solução para o seu problema, abaixo tem o exemplo dela já implementada com o código que você passou. Só não usei o foreach, pois já substitui direto, mas se quiser pode percorrer com um comando de repetição, armazenar o node em um array e depois percorrer novamente e a [substituir](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.replacechild.php) ou [adicionar](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.appendchild.php). Você pode [remover](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/domnode.removechild.php) nós que não desejar também.

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);


$doc = new DOMDocument;
// Pegar o conteudo do side 1, um pagina web
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.astralsaudeambiental.com.br/');
// Pegar o elemento com id sidebar
$doc1Sidebar = $doc->getElementById('sidebar');

// Pegar o conteúdo do site 2
$doc2 = new DOMDocument;
$doc2->loadHTML('<html>'
        . '<head>'
        . '<title>titulo</title>'
        . '</head>'
        . '<body>'
        . '<div style="width:200px;height:200px;background:#000000;"></div>'
        . '<div id="sidebar">'
        . '<div></div>'
        . '</div>'
        . '</body>'
        . '</html>');

$doc2Sidebar = $doc2->getElementById('sidebar');
// Importa o node
$newNode = $doc2->importNode($doc1Sidebar, true);
// Substitui o node
$doc2Sidebar->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $doc2Sidebar);


echo '<pre>';
echo $doc2->saveXML();
echo '</pre>';
```

> Há também outras formar de trabalhar com manipulação desses tipos de
>   documentos, sem a necessidade de trabalhar diretamente com o
>   DOMDocument, você pode tentar usar o [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) ou ainda o
>   [DomCrawler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html), são alternativas que podem ser bem atraentes.

Comment: @brasofilo, (off-topic) erro meu. Na realidade não é bem plágio, mas eu deveria ter colocado as referências e citações. Isso não se repetirá.

Comment: @brasofilo você está certo. Foi algo inconsciente, me empolguei na hora de responder. E cometi esse erro mesmo em muitas tags. Por favor, rejeite ou exclua, os que eu enviar vou colocar a fonte e desculpa esse trabalho todo. Não vai se repetir.

Comment: Sem problema, o erro é de quem aprovou as edições, se fossem rejeitadas você teria se dado conta. De todos modos, legal seu trabalho de preencher as tags vazias ;)